# How to Store and Retrieve Values in Redis using Javascript in Azure Function

Tags: javascript, redis, azure-functions

I am trying to connect to Redis in Azure functions, However I am getting timeout issue, but the same code runs well in vanilla  JS. What would be the ideal way to connect with redis within Azure functions ? And once function is executed how should it be disconnected ?

```
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {

const str = generateString();
if (context.req.method === 'POST') {
    const redisClient = createClient({ password: process.env['DB_PASSWORD'], socket: { host: process.env['DB_URL'], port: Number(process.env['DB_PORT']) } });
    redisClient.on("error", (error) => console.error(`Error : ${error}`));
    await redisClient.connect();

    await redisClient.setEx("str", 600, str);
    context.res.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json'
    context.res = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        body: {
            str
        }
    };
}
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create redis cache in azure and select your resource group as below:
  [image]
- Now create a http trigger function in JavaScript as below:
  [image]
- Now after creating the http trigger use the following commands to connect azure Redis cache:
- Replace host, port in the below commands from azure cache under keys in overview:
  [image]
  [image]
- Code:

```js
const redis = require("redis");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  const client = redis.createClient({
    host: "your.redis.cache.windows.net",
    port: ***,
    password: "***",
    tls: { servername: "your.redis.cache.windows.net" },
  });
```

I tried your given code It will disconnect within 10 minutes, You have to retrieve data  within this time Limit.

- I have performed and got the output as below for connection:
  [image]
- Now for disconnection you can use the below command:
  `client.quit(); // This is the command to disconnect`